# Should i use Elementary OS for developing applications?

Tags: user

I'm a Full stack web & React developer. I want to use Linux as it is favored by many professionals but it lacks good design. I've heard Elementary OS has a good design. Should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like other distros' UX/ergonomics then you won't like Elementary OS. If your issue is more aesthetic then you might like Elementary OS. The polish is largely surface level, but the core applications and feel are going to be reminiscent of other Debian based distros.

I, for one, can't stand development in Windows and don't choose to pay the Apple tax. I like Ubuntu, Mint, and Elementary for user-friendly distros.

Comment: ubuntu is awesome but lacks adobe creative cloud and other designer stuff

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would download a heap of different distros to live USB sticks and just boot each one at a time and find the one you like best. Most of them work in a very simular way.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can switch to elementary os (linux) and you will find all your tools and ides

but if you are a new user to linux i recommend start with ubuntu Because you will find a lot of guides and tutorials online and you can switch to elementary os later on

And I'll give you advice the descriptions don't mater they are all the same

you can change the look for your description by search for how to change desktop environment for your description (ubuntu)

if you any Questions hesitate